# Soft Keyboard overlaps an EditText in a TabHost

Tags: android, android-layout

I know that similar questions have been asked before , but I'm unable to figure out what to do with my layout.

**The problem:**
The keyboard overlaps the AutoCompleteTextView when many lines are added to it. I have tried wrapping everything in a scrollview and so on but that didn't help.
[image]
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/tabsScroll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="@null">
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <ScrollView
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/InputOuterContainer"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
                <View
                    android:background="#ffcccccc"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1.0px" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/InputContainer">
                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/InputTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/Ready"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:imeOptions="actionGo"
                        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                        android:focusable="true" />
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/ButtonRun"
                        android:paddingLeft="16.0dip"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/go"
                        android:scaleType="center"
                        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                        android:layout_gravity="top" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: try setting the android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" attribute in your manifest.

Comment: it did indeed work... but the tab headers are now hidden

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" may this attribute help u in adjusting u r ui for keyboard launch.

Comment: Paste a screenshot...

Comment: @MaryJ. Were you able to find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, in your manifest, add **android:windowSoftInputMode** to your activity,

check this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

then set **android:windowSoftInputMode** to **adjustPan** or **adjustResize**

Answer (score 0):

I added this line in the ScrollView tag:

```
android:isScrollContainer="false"
```